# how can I customize UV map the brick texture in geometric nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

how can I make a kerpich texture so that it reflects correctly?

---

[image]

For some reason, this method does not work. I want to arrange the texture in geo nodes, not in materials. is it possible? maybe I connected something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Chris's answer uses a Cube node, that provides the UV Map for you. I imagine what he wanted to show with his example is what to do when you have a geometry without UV provided (or if you want to experiment with the "UV Unwrap" node). But for the primitives with "UV Map" output socket, you simply need to store it as your UVMap attribute:

[image]

You also no longer need to access this UV Map as a general *attribute*, you can access it as a *UV map*, which is used by default, and therefore I disconnected the leftmost node to show it's not necessary:

[image]

Except... It's a little bit buggy currently  so you need to do something silly in geonodes to... I don't know... Refresh it?

[image]

[image]

P.S. Oh, right, I used a color grid texture in the file, but in principle it's the same for brick texture - except the brick texture by default uses "Generated" coordinate, so you **do need** to connect the leftmost node (UV Map node)

Comment: thanks for the reply) but I can't get the texture of the brick to be positioned correctly (

Comment: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6l1p.png

Comment: @AndreyRe you simply don't have enough geometry to store the brick texture on it - you need to subdivide the cube heavily to get the effect you're going for. This is precisely why uv maps exist - so the drawing can be done in shader, not geometry.

Answer (score 3):

this depends always on your geometry. But for a cube you can use this node setup:

[image]